# Creating a bitmap .jpg file with Qr-Code is different local then on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bitmap, qr-code

I'm Creating a bitmapfile with text and a QrCode
On my local machine this is generated perfect.
If i deploy it on the UAT server the image is not as I wanted.

The regional settings on the server is the same as on my local machine.

What could't be the possible reasons of this.

I don't think the code is a problem but see below.

Here I create the Image

```
        var qrCode = GenerateQrCode(url);
        using (Image emptyImage = new Bitmap(500, 600))
        {

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(emptyImage))
            {

                var font = new Font("Ariel", 26, FontStyle.Bold,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                graphics.DrawString(QrPortal.BLL.Resources.lmame.ToUpper(), font, Brushes.Black, 75, 15);

                using (var qrImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(qrCode)))
                {
                    graphics.DrawImage(qrImage, 50, 70);
                }
                graphics.DrawString(@QrPortal.BLL.Resources.scanme, font, Brushes.Black, 180, 500);
            }

            emptyImage.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        }
```

Here I create the QrCode

```
    private static Byte[] GenerateQrCode(string url)
    {
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(url, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.H);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
        var qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(9);

        return qrCodeImage.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

[image: Local generated]

[image: server generated img]

Comment: What's wrong with the image generated on the server?

Comment: the size of the image is not correct it is cut of at the left.
And the text i generate is inside my qr code.
As u see on my edit the qr-code has become bigger